# static method to return datasource in restful service

Tags: java, database, static, jersey

I have designed my connection factory class like below in my restful project, but got confused with the usage of static keyword after going through several posts online and in stackoverflow. Please help me to clarify my doubt on this design whether it's bad or good.

```
public class ConnectionFactory{
public Connection lookupConnection(){
//lookup datasource from application server
return connection;
}
}
```

And in my REST resource class do some operation on connection Object obtained with the help of ConnectionFactory object

```
@Path("/mypath")
public class RestSample{

public Response updateDetails(MyObj obj)
{
   Connection conn=new ConnectionFactory().lookupConnection();
   return conn.doSomeOperation();
}
}
```

I know this will work perfectly fine in multithreaded environment but am I unnecessarily creating object of ConnectionFactory for each request? Should I instead make method lookupConnection as static and refer using class name ConnectionFactory as the method doesn't refer to any global variable? Won't this cause any concurrency issue when many users invoke the service?

Answer (score 0):

You can either declare lookupConnection as `static`, which I would not prefer.
I would prefer a design pattern called Singleton:

```
public class ConnectionFactory{
private ConnectionFactory conFactory;

//prevent instanciation from outside
private ConnectionFactory() {}

public static synchronized getFactory() {
  if(ConnectionFactory.conFactory == null) { ConnectionFactory.conFactory = new ConnectionFactory(); }
  return ConnectionFactory.conFactory;
}

//methods of object are non-static
}
```

This class is thread-safe. Be aware of `synchronized`, you need it because object creation is not an atomic operation in JVM.
Acces your Factory by calling `ConnectionFactory.getFactory()` from anywhere in your code. The method will give you an object, if it was not created yet it will do so for you.

Comment: Thank you for quick response, do we really need singleton in this case? because I am already using connection pool provided by server,the above method returns a connection object from pool. If 2 REST URL's say A & B access lookupConnection at same time what will happen with static and without static? Because singleton will limit connection object to one per JVM which is not the expected behavior in this case.

Comment: As your class has no static variables, this would work. But since your class manages content, thats not in your 'hand' (looking up a connection), I would not use a static method for logical reasons. Can you look up a connection if no connectionFactory exists? Think about it and tell me, so I can adjust my answer:)

Comment: I did not get your point, connectionFactory  is a class so without class object or reference how a method can be accessed?

Comment: You can use a static method and access it by calling ConnectionFactory.method(). In case of performance, this will not be slower or faster than using a singleton. It's more a thing of logic, you need to answer the question: Can I call this method without having a concrete object of it?. For example: Can you call drive() on a car without a concrete car object? Do you get it now?